# Haskell: why is failing with equals symbols?

Tags: haskell

I'm having an issue that is frustrating me a bit. I have the next really simple code:

```hs
describe "functions" $ do
    it "can create a function" $ do
       mysum :: a -> a
       let mysum x = x + 1

       mysum 5
```

But is not compiling, the error I'm having is:

```
    error: Variable not in scope: mysum :: a -> a
   |        
15 |        mysum ::  a -> a
```

From the books I'm reading seems everything fine to me, and in internet seems that shouldn't fail my code, am I missing something?

Also I tried more alternatives:

```
       let b = mysum :: a -> a
       let b x = x + 1

       b 5
```

And

```
       let b = a -> a
       let b x = x + 1

       b 5
```

But in all of them I have errors

Comment: i think that you cannot constraint `Int a` as `Int` has kind `*`

Comment: The error message is correct. To define a value like that in a `do` block, you need to use `let`.

Comment: The `Int` typeclass does not exist (well at least not in the `base`). Furthermore in the `do` you can not define functions like that. You then would need a `let`.

Comment: Oh god, in just 3 lines I see I have multiple bad things..thanks guys, I will focus on all those feedbacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To define a function with a signature in a `do`-block, you need to put *both* its signature and its definition inside the same `let`. Indentation matters. For instance,

```
example = do
   something1
   something2
   let mysum :: Num a => a -> a
       mysum x = x + 1  -- same indentation as "mysum" above
   something3  -- we can use mysum here
   something4
```

Concretely:

```
describe "functions" $ do
    it "can create a function" $ do
       let mysum :: Num a => a -> a
           mysum x = x + 1
       mysum 5 `shouldBe` (6 :: Int)
```

The above declares a polymorphic `mysum`, as you tried to do. If we instead define a more basic `mysum :: Int -> Int`, we do not need to specify that `6` is an `Int` in the very last line, since that's already deduced.